# JavaFx 8 - A class that has a border than you're able to color and able to have text in the middle of it

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8

Does anyone know of a class that i can use that is essential a rectangle, BUT it has text in the middle of the rectangle and the rectangle has a fill color along with a border color(the border can be changed to red or something along those lines)

Essentially right now i have a pane, and i want to make a 2D grid(10x10), where each individual object in the grid is a rectangle-typed object that has a number text center justified, a fill color, and a border color.

Note: I've tried to use gridpane, but the lack of documentation that i've found has led me to believe i can only set the fill color, and each cell in the grid pane does NOT look like a separate object like i want it to. I've also tried to implement rectangle but the rectangle doesn't have text or a border that i can manipulate.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be able to use a Label, and just configure it using CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `Label`. Here's a proof of concept:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomLabelDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Hello World");
        label.setStyle(
            "-fx-alignment: center;"
            +"-fx-padding: 6px;"
            +"-fx-background-color: red, -fx-background;"
            +"-fx-background-insets: 0, 4px;"
        );
        StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 75));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The way the css is working here is that it defines two backgrounds: the first (and thus the one at the back) is red; the one in front is set to `-fx-background`, which is the color defined in the default stylesheet for the background of most controls. Corresponding to these are two insets for the two backgrounds: the first set to zero, and the second set to 4 pixels. This means that 4 pixels of the red border will be visible. The padding is just set to make sure the text doesn't overlap the outer background (the border).

In a real application, you should put the style in an external file. You can also define a ["looked-up-color"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) for the border color; this will make it much easier to change the color at runtime:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomLabelDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Hello World");
        label.getStyleClass().add("custom-label");

        Button changeColorButton = new Button("Change to green");
        changeColorButton.setOnAction(event -> label.setStyle("custom-label-border-color: green;"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, label, changeColorButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("custom-label.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with custom-label.css:

```
.custom-label {
    custom-label-border-color: red ;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-padding: 6px;
    -fx-background-color: custom-label-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 4px;
}

.button {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
```

If you have a fixed set of states that the colors represent, you might want to use a pseudoclass to represent the state:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomLabelDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Hello World");
        label.getStyleClass().add("custom-label");

        CheckBox errorCheckBox = new CheckBox("Error");
        PseudoClass errorState = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");
        errorCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> 
            label.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorState, isNowSelected));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, label, errorCheckBox);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("custom-label.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

custom-label.css:

```
.custom-label {
    custom-label-border-color: green ;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-padding: 6px;
    -fx-background-color: custom-label-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 4px;
}

.custom-label:error {
    custom-label-border-color: red ;
}

.check-box {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would you access the border color though ? Say that the object [6] the [] is supposed to be a square how would you change the label's black outline to something else?

Comment: Well, the border is red in that example. A quick and dirty way to change the border color is just to call setStyle(...) again, with 'red' replaced by the color you want. But there are better ways, I will update when I am back st a computer.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is to make a custom control, exposing the properties you need.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm for info and examples.

Comment: That's way overkill for this. `Label` already has everything you need to do this.